# Highscharts not working after array passed array_diff

Tags: php, arrays, highcharts

I need to remove values = 99 from array. But after the `array_diff` the Highcharts doesn't show any data anymore.

```
$a = array ("$object->hdc_wed_01", "$object->hdc_wed_02", "$object->hdc_wed_03", "$object->hdc_wed_04", "$object->hdc_wed_05", "$object->hdc_wed_06", "$object->hdc_wed_07", "$object->hdc_wed_08", "$object->hdc_wed_09", "$object->hdc_wed_10", "$object->hdc_wed_11", "$object->hdc_wed_12", "$object->hdc_wed_13", "$object->hdc_wed_14", "$object->hdc_wed_15", "$object->hdc_wed_16", "$object->hdc_wed_17", "$object->hdc_wed_18", "$object->hdc_wed_19", "$object->hdc_wed_20", "$object->hdc_wed_21", "$object->hdc_wed_22", "$object->hdc_wed_23", "$object->hdc_wed_24", "$object->hdc_wed_25", "$object->hdc_wed_26", "$object->hdc_wed_27", "$object->hdc_wed_28", "$object->hdc_wed_29", "$object->hdc_wed_30", "$object->hdc_wed_31", "$object->hdc_wed_32", "$object->hdc_wed_33", "$object->hdc_wed_34", "$object->hdc_wed_35");
$b = array (99);
$c = array_diff($a, $b);
$handicaps = json_encode($c);
$handicaps_clean = str_replace('"',"", $handicaps);
```

If I'm using `$handicaps = json_encode($a);`  (the unfiltered array) it works fine, but the values equal to 99 are in it. I want to remove them.

Comment: So, you have 100 values and you need which one? The first one? `$c = reset($a);` The last one? `$c = end($a);`

Comment: No i got 35 values but some off them are or can be the number 99. They need to be removed form the array.

Comment: You have used highcharts tag, but the problem doesn't seem to be about a chart - rather about data. If you'll have problems with Highcharts then please provide a demo with hard-coded, exemplary data.

Answer (score 0):

As I clearly understood you there's an array of values like `$ar = [3,5,2,5,6,7,99,6,5,7,8,99]` and some specific array with non-desired values like `$remove = [99]`.

If so, then you can use [unset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) function to remove such elements from `$ar`:

```
$ar = [3,5,2,5,6,7,99,6,5,7,8,99];
$remove = [99];

foreach($ar as $ind => $val){
    if (in_array($val,$remove)) unset($ar[$ind]);
}
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 6
    [5] => 7
    [7] => 6
    [8] => 5
    [9] => 7
    [10] => 8
)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/PiIIR)

Hope you've figured out the idea.

Comment: This helped. At first highcharts did not show any data. Until i added:
$a = array_values($a); 
Seems like for some reason the index of the array got messed up after the unset.

Comment: @SvenFroeling, yes, that's how `unset` works, it removes element from array with its index at once. If you need to save this index and define default value for it you could use `$ar[$ind] = $value;` instead of `unset($ar[$ind]);`